# How to read files in a subdirectory with node.js?

Tags: node.js, directory

I have a subdirectory called dev inside of my root folder that I want to pull data from html files (Just the `<title>` element).

```
root
  |- dev
  |   |-foo.html
  |   |-bar.html
  |
  |--main.js
  |--package.json
  |--...
```

My main application runs in the root and watches for changes. I need the application navigate to the dev folder and run my script, asynchronously. I used:

```
process.chdir('../root/dev');
```

to change the directory but my application quits.

How do I change directories without my application dying?

Comment: Most watcher libraries should notify what changed; also, I am not sure why you need to go out of your process folder (`root`), if you are already in `root`, shouldn't just be a simple `./dev/...`?

Comment: @Erick The application lives in the root folder and has to pull data from the html files and generate a json file to be placed into the root folder. There is a second part of the application that needs to watch for changes in the folder with grunt.

Comment: So, you are using grunt, that is a good piece of information. How are you watching those files? The more information we have, the better we could figure it out. Also, have you tried to replicate a minimal setup (only watcher and html files) to see if the same happens without the rest of code?

Comment: I'm using a module that generates files for live use. The dev folder holds those files during development. Grunt is suppose to watch the dev folder for updates and create live page that are placed in another folder inside the root.
I want to add another function that runs asynchronously to get data from folder and generate a json file with that data to be put into the root folder.

Comment: @Erick I just need to be able to let the part of the application I'm adding to work on it's own, and run once everything time I initiate the grunt command.